# Adding the possibility to write a AST-file to my (rail-)compiler

Tags: haskell, if-statement, compiler-construction, io-monad

I'm writing rail-compiler (rail is an esoteric language) in Haskell and I get some problems within the main-function of my mainmodule.

1) I want my program to ask wheter I want to run the compiling-pipeline or simply stop after the lexer and write the AST to a file so another compiler can deal with my AST (Abstract Synatx Tree). Here is my program:

```
module Main (
             main   -- main function to run the program
            )
 where

 -- imports --
 import InterfaceDT as IDT
 import qualified Testing as Test
 import qualified Preprocessor as PreProc
 import qualified Lexer
 import qualified SyntacticalAnalysis as SynAna
 import qualified SemanticalAnalysis as SemAna
 import qualified IntermediateCode as InterCode
 import qualified CodeOptimization as CodeOpt
 import qualified Backend

 -- functions --
 main :: IO()
 main = do putStr "Enter inputfile (path): "
           inputfile <- getLine
           input <- readFile inputfile
           putStr "Enter outputfile (path): "
           outputfile <- getLine
           input <- readFile inputfile

           putStr "Only create AST (True/False): "
           onlyAST <- getLine
           when (onlyAST=="True") do putStrLn "Building AST..."
                                     writeFile outputfile ((Lexer.process . PreProc.process) input)
           when (onlyAST=="False") do putStrLn ("Compiling "++inputfile++" to "++outputfile)
                                      writeFile outputfile ((Backend.process . CodeOpt.process . InterCode.process . SemAna.process . SynAna.process . Lexer.process . PreProc.process) input)
```

I get an error in Line 21 (`input <- readFile inputfile`) caused by the `<-`. Why?

How should I do it?

2) Next thing is that I want to refactor the program in that way, that I can call it from the terminal with parameters like `runhaskell Main(AST)` (in that way it should just create the AST) or like `runhaskell Main.hs` (in that way it should do the whole pipeline).

I hope for your help!

Comment: What is the error message that you got?

Answer (score 1):

For your error in (1), your program doesn't *look* syntactically incorrect at line 21 to me.  However an error at `<-` would happen if that line were indented differently from the previous one. I suspect that you are having an indentation error due to mixing tabs and spaces in a way that looks correct in your editor but disagrees with Haskell's interpretation of tabs. The simplest recommendation is to always use spaces and never tabs.

You also have an extra copy of that line later, which you might want to remove.

I also suspect you may need to use `hFlush stdin` after your putStr's, for them to work as prompts.

For (2), I'd suggest using a library for proper command line argument and option parsing, such as [System.Console.GetOpt](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/System-Console-GetOpt.html) which is included with GHC, or one of the fancier ones which you can find on Hackage.